# Robolectric and gms/maps

Tags: android, robolectric

### Update:

The issue seems to be with GooglePlayServices byte code not having the stackmap frame. Not sure if it matters or not but I am using JDK 8.  **There have been reported workarounds by using a back level of GooglePlayServices, however as a workaround (for now at least) I added the  `-noverify` flag to the default VM options for JUnit under Run->editConfigurations, and my tests now pass.  I am still looking for a cleaner solution if anyone has one.**

---

I am trying to get some tests running again after updating a somewhat old project (when I last worked on it I was using android studio 1.0x, now I am on 1.5.1).

I have migrated to Robolectric 3.0, but I am having some issues with some tests that use gms/maps.  Here is an example of the stack trace I get:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 15
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.writeToParcel(Landroid/os/Parcel;I)V @3: ifeq
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b800 1b99 000c 2a2b 1cb8 001f a700 092a
    0000010: 2b1c b800 1eb1                         

    at com.gmail.npnster.ourlatitude.MapMarker.getLatLng(MapMarker.java:143)
```

I have the following in my build.gradle file

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-maps:3.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.0'
```

The test class has the following annotaions:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, shadows = {ShadowGooglePlayServicesUtil.class} )
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
```

and the line where the fail occurs is the return statement in the method below

```
public LatLng getLatLng() {
    return new LatLng(mMarker.getLatitude(), mMarker.getLongitude());
}
```

This worked a while back when I was using Robolectric 2.4,  but I am not sure if this is an issue with how I have Robolectric setup, or if I have some other issue.  The app itself seems to run fine.

Comment: Can you add `sdk=21` to your `@Config`?

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot ... currently broken for other reasons :)